# MSE loss function calculation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, seq2seq

I trained a seq2seq network using input samples with a shape of [30,26] and output shape of [1,7] with MSE as the loss function (`model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam"`). However, when I compare `history.history['loss']` to
`keras_error = tf.keras.losses.MSE(predictions_train, data_train)` (returns an array of errors which I averaged) the results differ by about 0.2. Insights on how the MSE loss function is calculated for an output sequence like this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The MSE loss is calculated in the same way. You have 7 values in both x and y. Both sides are subtracted from each other then squared then divided by 7. The reason your values are coming like that can be because `model.compile` is using `tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError` while you are using another function. This kind of discrepancy can come because of this. But, the end game is the performance of the network, is that getting fulfilled?